# 8 mo/2.5 lb Yorkie SCREAMS when scolded

Tags: behavior

This cute tiny guy SCREAMS as I've never heard before from any dog ever, it's frightening! This only occurs if he is scolded or during grooming if he wants you to stop. I truly believe he knows this action is power and uses it, as he is not being hurt or does he seem frightened. I was told by breeder after I purchased him, that he was sold and returned once before for same behavior, frightening the couple. I have tried distraction, walking away, ignoring... Nothing has worked. I love the little loud mouth, how do I stop this behavior as the neighbors must think I'm torquering him!

Comment: 8 months old... how long have you worked with each strategy?

Comment: I purchased him at 5 mo, so have bonded and worked with behavior for 3 mo. I prefer the distraction method and have used it the most over 3 mo. This SCREAMING has lessened but pops up from time to time and with groomers, which freaks them out!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently that is this particular dog's fear reaction.  I don't think it's a good idea to try training it out of the reaction itself, but training it to no longer fear these situations should help.  I recommend focusing on positive reinforcement rather than negative reinforcement such as scolding to train this dog, since it seems to react really badly to scolding.  As for the groomers, try slowly desensitizing the dog to the kinds of things you expect it to get at the groomers.  For instance, gently restrain the dog, for a short period of time, rewarding behavior with treats.  Slowly work up the amount of time the dog is restrained.  Start working in gently handling legs and head as the groomer would.  Eventually you might start using scissors or clippers near the dog.